# javascript button onclick to a web uri with location.href

Tags: javascript, html, button, onclick, uri

I am trying to add a onclick function to a button outside of the `<button>` tag, in Javascript. Below is what I have at the moment, but the button doesn't links to that uri when clicked. How should I do this? Many thanks for your help in advance! I commented in the code as well.

For the button I have:

```
"<td><button"+" id="+foodList[i].Id +" onClick="+"\"doSomething(this.id)\""+" >"+"Get"+"</button></td></tr>"
```

So basically I assigned the "Get" button an id in a for loop.

```
function doSomething(id) { //the button's id
  var item = document.getElementById("type").value; //get some value from elsewhere in the page
  if (item == "food") {
    var uri = "baseuri" + id;
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = "location.href='" + uri + "';"//add an onclick to the button so that it will takes the user to that uri       
  } else {
    var uri = "another baseuri" + id;
    document.getElementById(id).onclick = "location.href='" + uri + "';"
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change this:

```
document.getElementById(id).onclick="location.href='"+uri+"';"
```

to something like this:

```
document.getElementById(id).onclick= function(){
    location.href = "Wanted url here"; // location.href = location.href + "/currentpath/additional/params/here"
}
```

That way, when you click the button, you have attached a function to it, and it changes the url (redirects the page)

Comment: Thanks for your reply! But what if it's not a window location, but some web uri?

Comment: @user3735871 Well it's the same thing. Just do something like this: `window.location = 'http://google.com'`

Comment: But what shall I do to the button tag in this case? It seems that if I add `onclick = doSomething(id)` to the `<button>` tag, I need to double click it in order to trigger the  function() to go to that uri..

Comment: What? No. Post some code. You're doing something wrong

Comment: I edited it in the question. So I have an `onclick=doSomething(id)` in the button tag, to link the button to the `doSomething` function. I must be doing it wrong. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

You must write it like this :

```
document.getElementById(id).onclick = function() {
    location.href = uri; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks mate. I don't know why the answer got a down vote. It works for me. I upvoted it

Comment: The problem is that when I add `onclick = doSomething(id)` to the `<button>` tag, I need to double click it in order to trigger the function() to go to that uri..